# Read Adobe Framemaker Documents natively in .Net?

Tags: .net, adobe, framemaker

Good afternoon,

does anyone know of a library that would allow me to read the content of adobe framemaker files/books natively in a .net application without having Adobe Framemaker installed (and as a prerequisite for my own application?).

Basically something like Aspose.Word / Cells that read Word / Excel files in natively.. but for framemaker.

Is there something like that available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of anything obvious, although if your app could deal with XML instead, you could hack together a solution that used dzbatcher or mif2go to export a copy of the files into source control or a shared directory somewhere.  You could then have a FrameMaker-equipped machine non-interactively spit out the copies at build time or at check-in.